# Duplo contexto de perguntas

Tags: debate

Quando uma pergunta de inicio aparenta ter um sentido, e no desenvolver dos comentários ela revela ter outro completamente diferente e eu responder ao conceito da pergunta inicial, a minha resposta deixa de ser "válida"?

Por outras palavras, [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94040/11886) o autor pergunta se é possível adicionar um `id` dentro de um atributo `title` da seguinte forma:

```
<div title="<span id=""></span>"> </div>
```

E eu [respondi que não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94044/11886) (pelo menos nesta lógica), mas enquanto criava a minha resposta, no desenvolver dos comentários acontece que a intenção do autor é um tanto diferente do contexto inicial da pergunta.
A minha resposta deixará de ser válida por ter respondido ao conceito inicial?
Será que devo eliminar a minha resposta por já não responder às necessidades do autor?

Comment: No meu ponto de vista se ou autor da pergunta não soube se expressar corretamente na pergunta e nos comentários ele descobre que quer outra coisa e não edita a pergunta, se sua resposta estiver de acordo com a pergunta dele que esta com uma finalidade diferente eu creio que ela ainda esteja valida, até o memento que o autor editar a pergunta e mudar sua própria necessidade.

Comment: Relacionado: [Será que esta é uma pergunta camaleão?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115/)